# Deploy Liferay Portlet wars via Jenkins?

Tags: liferay, setup-deployment, jenkins-plugins

We are trying to automate the process of deploying the generated war files via Jenkins to web server. I was able to achieve the same for normal war files using Deploy plugin over tomcat server.

For Liferay portlet war files, I can't use the same plugin as we put war files into deploy folder in liferay and then it gets copied over to tomcat webapps folder.

Another approach I see is to add the deploy path in pom.xml    `<properties>
        <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>${deployPath}</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.version>6.1.0</liferay.version>
    </properties>` and then run the maven command **mvn package liferay:deploy** to copy to deploy directory.

Do you have any other option or thoughts, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the wars using Jenkins then alternative would be using Liferay Plugin SDK provided Ant task that provides "ant deploy" command.

For maven projects the mvn liferay:deploy IS the correct and proper way of doing it!

Here's a link to the latest dev. guide on that subject:
https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-a-portlet-project-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en